# Bigcommerce API (oAuth) Webhook Request - what is {secret_auth_password}?

Tags: oauth, bigcommerce

**UPDATE:** All calls to the API receive the following response:

```
failed [500] An error has occurred
```

Weirdly, my auth process (documented [here](https://gist.github.com/axwaxw/c3709af032bd83c4b6e9#file-methods_api-js)) works perfectly, while all calls to the API (documented [here](https://gist.github.com/axwaxw/c3709af032bd83c4b6e9#file-methods_api-js)), fail.

---

The Bigcommerce API is in transition from basic auth to oAuth.  The [documentation](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/) is consequently a little confusing.

I am trying to create a webhook using the new oAuth methodology.  The [documentation](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/webhooks-getting-started) states that I need an oAuth access_token for the relevant store, which I have obtained.

The [documentation](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/webhooks#create-hook) also includes sample http request data:

```
{
  "scope": "store/order/*",
  "headers": {
    "X-Custom-Auth-Header": "{secret_auth_password}"
  },
  "destination": "https://app.example.com/orders",
  "is_active": true
}
```

In this context, I am assuming that `{secret_auth_password}` refers to the store's access_token.  However, when I include the access_token here I get the following error:

```
failed [401] You are not authorized.
```

Thinking that this might be a scoping/permission issue, I have given my app the highest possible level of access through the app settings, but this did not work either.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Webhooks documentation just rolled out last week. I agree it is a little light still. Can you provide more detail such as where you are sending the request to?

Comment: I am using [Meteor](http://www.meteor.com) and my process is written in javaScript (node.js) and is documented in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/axwaxw/c3709af032bd83c4b6e9)

Comment: Does your store hash only have 5 characters? I feel like usually there are 6.

Comment: @AlexWebster do you receive request from bigCommerce to you Hook URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after a couple of days of serious head-scratching (not to mention hair out-tearing) I worked out that this was all down to an error in my **SSL intermediate certificate**, which I have now fixed.

It was the *old* API returning an error of **“UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE”** that put me on the right track – the new API just returned:

```
500 – there is an error
```

or

```
404 – you are not authorized.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP I would recommend using the the Webhooks pull request combined with the OAuth pull request. They are both working fine together (I personally use them).

Webhooks pull - https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php/pull/101

OAuth pull - https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php/pull/88

Then to create a webhook you can just call `createWebhook($object)`

Object needs to include `scope` and `destination`.

Also - a side note.. Are you using SSL for the destination address. It won't work otherwise. You can use a self-signed cert to get around this though.

This will only work for setting up the webhooks though.

To actually receive them you need a valid certificate (else you get nothing).

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks but I am using javascript on Meteor.  I had thought that it was an https issue, but having shifted everything to https I get the same error.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions that you have on the store (from the 'scope' identifier) ?

Comment: Thanks - yes per my question I have granted my app the highest possible access.  Weirdly, the AUTH process works perfectly while the API process only ever receives [500] errors

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same part of the documentation and was also confused by it.  The proper headers to send for webhooks are the following:

```
"X-Auth-Client":"[YOUR_APPS_CLIENT_ID]",
"X-Auth-Token":"[OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN]"
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using the headers that @FlyingL123 suggested, also take note of of the requirements as noted by BigCommerce:

> Requirements
>
> The following properties of the webhooks are required. The request
>   won’t be fulfilled unless these properties are valid.
>
> ```
> scope
> destination
> ```